# should I use float or classes as output for the final layer in my neural network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I am working on a deep learning problem where I am trying to predict time-to-failure on laboratory earthquake data from an observed seismic time series. The target is a single integer number (the time until the next earthquake) ranging, say, from 1 to 10.

I could design the last layer to return a single float and use, say, mean-square-error(MSE), as a loss to make that returned float close to the desired integer. Or, I could think of each integer possibility as a "class" and use a cross-entropy(CE) loss to optimize.

Are there any arguments in favour of either of these options?

Also, what if the target is a float number ranging from 1 to 10? I could also turn this into a class/CE problem.

So far, I have tried the CE option (which works at some level) and am thinking of trying the mse option but wanted to step back and think before proceeding. Such thoughts would include reasoning as to why one approach might outperform the other.

I am working with pytorch version 1.0.1 and Python 3.7.

Thanks for any guidances.

Comment: Could it not be considered: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: With a specific application, perhaps.  The current generic explanation without use cases suggests a more generic discussion elsewhere.

Comment: If I add to the question that I am using the pytorch package, would that make the question viable? Would it help if I explained in more detail the problem that I am attempting to solve?

Comment: I have done both of the above - is that better? Hopefully, I can learn the rules governing the posing of acceptable questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just implement a float head with an L1Loss in Pytorch and I created a simple but effective synthetic data set to test the implementation. The data set created images into which a number of small squares were randomly drawn. The training label was simply the number of squares divided by 10, a float number with one decimal digit.
The net trained very quickly and to a high degree of precision - the test samples were correct to the one decimal digit.

As to the original question, the runs I made definitely favoured the float over class.

My take on this is that the implementation in classes had a basic imprecision in the assignment of the classes and, perhaps more importantly, the class implementation has no concept of a "metric". That is, the float implementation, even if it misses the exact match, will try to generate an output label "close" to the input label while the class implementation has no concept of "close".

One warning with Pytorch. If you are fitting to one float, be sure to encase it in a length 1 vector in the data generator. Pytorch cannot handle a "naked" float number (even though it does become a vector when batches are done). But it doesn't complain. This cost me a bunch of time.